# Extract files from FreeBSD ISOs - how to know locations?

Tags: package-management, freebsd, cross-compilation, header-file

How can I extract some of the folders of a stock FreeBSD install from the ISO without actually installing FreeBSD?

I am trying to build a number of cross-compilers for various major versions of FreeBSD and need to get the `libc` and some includes and would like to be able to extract `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` or rather parts of them ...

**Edit:** given the first response I feel I have to elaborate a bit. It is trivial to mount an ISO file and I know how to do that on a number of platforms (e.g. on my Linux box: `mount -o loop FreeBSD-7.0-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso freebsd7/`). However, when you mount the installation ISOs for FreeBSD you will notice that they don't contain a folder `usr` as can be easily seen from the output of `find -type d -name usr` while inside the folder in which the ISO is mounted. Evidently the files are stored away in some format and I need to be able to parse whatever meta-information exists to find what file is the archive that contains the stuff I need to extract and then extract it.

Comment: The files from e.g. ftp://ftp.fr.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/8.2-RELEASE/base/ are extracted with: `cat base.?? | tar --unlink -xpzf -` (not sure if the archive in base/ has the /usr you seek)

Comment: @hhaamu's hint is good, there's a file called [`base.mtree`](http://ftp.fr.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/8.2-RELEASE/base/base.mtree) that gives some insight, i.e. lists what's in the `base.??` files -- and it does mention `gcc`.

Comment: @hhaamu: can you write that up as an answer, please? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the files from e.g. ftp://ftp.fr.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/8.2-RELEASE/base/ (you can probably find them on your ISO, too), you can extract them with this:

```
cat base.?? | tar --unlink -xpzf -
```

(taken from the `install.sh` in the same directory)

In addition, the `base.mtree` file describes the contents of the archive.

There are other archives to be found, too. For example, `manpages` which contains the manual pages to be put in `/usr/share/man/`, `kernels` which contains the kernel modules, and `dict` which contain wordlists to be put in `/usr/share/dict/`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this (at least with the `FreeBSD-9.0-RELEASE-i386-disc1.iso` image) by mounting the ISO image to some location and them perform the file operations from there. Something like:

```
# mkdir /mnt/freebsd
# mount -t auto /path/to/install_image.iso /mnt/freebsd
# cp -r /mnt/freebsd/usr/include /some/other/location
  ...
# umount /mnt/freebsd
```

No need to install anything. So after you have everything, simply unmount the ISO and continue hacking. This seems to be the simplest way I can think of.

Comment: Okay, I had to use `mount -o loop` because I'm on Linux. So I have a FreeBSD 7 ISO mounted. However, `find -type d -name usr` gives me an empty set. I would not have asked the question if it was that trivial as I knew how to mount it. The problem is how to find the files that are apparently packed up in some way. I edited my question.